# Meaning of said of

Tags: usage

In the following sentence

> Highlighting his government’s achievements, Mr. Modi **said of** the 675 km of Metro lines in operation in the country, 400 km had been built in the last five years. He said work is under way on nearly 850 km of Metro lines. Mr. Modi said, “In the next five years, we will be spending ₹100 lakh crore on infrastructure projects, which will benefit Mumbai and other cities as well.”

Is **said of** correctly used?

I have never seen such usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrasal verb "(to) say of" is normal and standard. To say something **of** a person or thing is to say something **about** that person or thing. Also teach of, speak of, sing of, write of, etc.

> **Of**
>
> preposition (RELATING TO) ​
>
> about; relating to:
>
> Speaking of Elizabeth, here she is.
>   And what of (= tell me about) young Adrian? How is he?

[Of (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of)

> It is said of the young John Evans that he intended during his
>   lifetime to build a city
>
> It is said of art that "I know it when I see it".
>
> It is said of Augustine (the one who wrote Confessions) that he worked
>   hard all day as a bishop and then worked all night as a theologian.
>
> It is said of Phidias that he alone had seen the exact image of the
>   gods.
>
> It was said of him that 'not only did he not mind accidents, he
>   positively liked them'.
>
> It was said of her that the king and chocolate were her only two
>   passions.